# How to use ECDSA keys in digital signature

Tags: c#, security, bouncycastle

I want to know if there 's a possibility to create a signature ECDSA, using a key pair generated with Bouncy Castle;

Indeed, with RSA for example, I generate keys with Bouncy Castle , then I save them in XML file, the purpose is to Use `FromXmlString` method in C#,

How I want to do the same thing with ECDSA, seen in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.aspx

Does `FromXmlStrin`g method have the same function?

Do you have any an idea about the format of a public and private keys ECDSA, in order to build my file XML properly? What are the tags and elements to be used to build this file)?

and what about `ECKeyXmlFormat.Rfc4050` in C#?

Is  ecdsa keys must use this format?

Answer (score 2):

[old questions clean up]

1. yes Bouncy can create ECDSA key pairs
2. that's a french MSDN site, and
   the English version is as useable to me, seems to me that you will
   have to build that XML structure yourself
3. Rfc4050 just uses X9.62,
   which everything else uses to encode keys in as well
4. no, you don't
   have to use this format, but it is the defacto standard